# Current Entry from Array in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm a newbie so be kind :) 
In Javascript, how do I add to a variable the current entry from an array? See my code below.

```
    <?php
        $array = mysql_query(SELECT column1 FROM table1 WHERE column2='$entry'); 
                                           //this returns several entries

        <script>
            var array=<?=json_encode($array)?>;   // the      
            var data={mouse:mickey, rabbit:roger};
                $.each(array, function(){
                        $.post('dostuff.php',data+','+{array[this]}); // <-- not sure
                        });
        </script>
    ?>
```

My question is about the data sent in the "post" jquery command. how do I add the current database entry and send it as part of the data sent in the ajax request. I wrote it roughly, but I'm confident it isn't right the way I wrote it here.

Thanks!

Comment: i know it won't that's why I'm asking :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add properties directly to your data object.  Also note that the supplied function for each can take an index, and a value parameter.

```
var array=<?=json_encode($array)?>;   // the      
var data={mouse:mickey, rabbit:roger};
 $.each(array, function(index, value){
      data.whatEverYouWantToNameThis = value;
      $.post('dostuff.php', data); 
 });
```

Comment: i get the syntax now, that's awesome. will this insert the current entry of the array into the post's data? or do i have to do that somehow separately?

Comment: Well `data` is what you're posting, so adding a property to `data` will add a property to what you're posting.  Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: Okay I get it now, "value" is extracted using the "each" function, and then it's inserted into the "data". awesome! great, tnx :-)

Comment: @LucyWeatherford - precisely.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

#### How do I fetch the data from MySQL?

`mysql_query` returns a handle to be used to actually fetch the result (kind of like a file handle when reading files).

You should use `mysql_fetch_array` which will give you a row from the result set, or `false` when you have reached the end.

Remember that the returned array from `mysql_fetch_array` will contain values with a number as key, as well as the field name as a key, you are probably only interested in the latter; then you should use `mysql_fetch_assoc`:

```
// please remember to sanitize $entry before using it in a SQL query.
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT column1 FROM table1 WHERE column2='$entry'");

$query_data = array ();

while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result)) !== false) {
  $query_data[] = $row;
}

...

<script>
  var array = <?=json_encode ($query_data);?>;

...
```

---

I read your post again, if you are only interested in the value of a single row and a single column then you should use `mysql_fetch_field` (pass it your `$result` from `mysql_query`).

That function will return the value in the first column (in your case `field1`).

Wrap this value in an array and use `json_encode` before giving it to your javascript.

---

**Documentation**

- [PHP: mysql_query - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)
- [PHP: mysql_fetch_assoc - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)
- [PHP: mysql_fetch_field - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-field.php)

---

#### How do I iterate over the array in javascript?

The callback sent to `jQuery.each` can optionally take two parameters.

1. the index of the current entry
2. the value of the current entry

With this knowledge you could write your function as:

```
$.each(array, function(idx, value){
  $.post('dostuff.php',[data, value]); 
});

// or.. (depending on what you wanna do)

var post_data = $.extend ({}, data, {array_data: array});

$.post ('dostuff.php', post_data);
```

Comment: I actually need the loop for the rest of the code's logic(it's in another loop and not all entries will actually run). but I like the "extend" function, cool! tnx for the help :)

Comment: Well, you are welcome.. even though I didn't even get an up-vote. but I'll leave my answer around for a while, someone else might appreciate it later.

Comment: @LucyWeatherford JFTR; you need 15 rep to up-vote, you are able.